# C++ Overloading output using vector

Tags: c++, vector, output, operator-overloading, overloading

o, I am attempting to create an overloaded output operator for a vector. This overloaded output operator is suppose to allow me to print the values in the vector in the form

[Data]^[Index]
so for example if the data at index 3 is 4, it should print 3^4.

However, I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I need it to loop through the entire vector, but I can't seem to detect what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the function within the header.

```
friend ostream & operator << (ostream &out, const vector<int> &c);
```

Here is what I have for the function in the source file.

```
ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const vector<int> &c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    {
        os << c.at[i];
        os << "^";
        os << i;

    }
    return os;
```

Finally, here is my main

```
#include "Polynomial.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>


int main()
{
    vector<int> poly1(10);
    vector<int> poly2(10);
    int x;
    int y;

    int choice;
    bool done = true;

    std::cout << "What do you wish to do?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Add two polynomials" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Multiply two polynomials" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Evaluate one polynomial at a given value" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. Find Coefficent for a given polynomial and given exponent" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. Find the leading exponent for a given polynomial" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6. Exit "<< std::endl;

    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice < 1 || choice > 6)
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid entry: please reenter choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> choice;


        } while (choice < 1 || choice > 6);
    }


    if (choice == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Please input the first polynomial in the form of: (non-zero coefficient, exponent) pairs" << std::endl;
        do
        {
            std::cin >> x >> y;
            poly1.at(y) = x;

            std::cout << "done?" << std::endl;

            std::cin >> done;
        } while (done == false);

        std::cout << poly1 << std::endl;
    }
    if (choice == 2)
    if (choice == 3)
    if (choice == 4)
    if (choice == 5)
    if (choice == 6)


    system("pause");
```

I believe that my issue lies somewhere within my main or within the source file, though I haven't worked with overloaded output operators in a very long time, so I'm not sure exactly what needs to be fixed.

Comment: You should have got a compiler error for `os << c.at[i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is somewhere else and it's actually hard to find in the first glimpse.

Here :

```
os << c.at[i];
```

`std::vector::at` is a function and it's the same as `std::vector operator []`, but it's a function and you can't use it like this. change it to :

```
os << c.at(i); //or os << c[i];
```

Two minor things to take care of :

1. it's better to print some delimiter(like `-`) when you print each `value^index` because it's hard to read this way.
2. in this line `for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)` to avoid getting `'<' : signed/unsigned mismatch` warning change it to `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)`. `std::vector::size` returns `size_type` which is an unsigned integral type.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with your code except that at is function so you cannot use subscript operator with that,hence correct code for the above problem is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
ostream & operator << (ostream &os, const vector<int> &c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
    {
        os << c.at(i);
        os << "^";
        os << i;

    }
    return os;
}
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
  std::cout<<v<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```